# Regular expression ([A-Za-z]*) matches digits and special characters?

Tags: java

i need to validate a text fiel in my application. this cant contain neither digit nor special char so i tried this regex:
[A-Za-z]*
The problem is that this regex doesn't work when i put a digit or a special char in the middle or at the end of the String.

Comment: Too many duplicates of something too simple that shows no prior research :( Well, *you tell me* what `[A-Za-z]*` means in a regular expression and then *I'll tell you* why it doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

to match text (1 or more in length) containing ASCII letters only.

Comment: I salute you anubhava.  If only I had entered 30 characters on the first try.

Comment: It's the same with all of the SO community here. People come up with answers pretty fast for simple questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and try `^[A-Za-z]*$` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following Regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]*$");
```

See a list of regex-specs on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

The pattern you describe will never work. Without the begin and end bonds the pattern will look for a substring that matches. Since an empty string is also allowed (star means 0 or more characters), one can simply use the empty string anywhere.

Comment: What we can add if we want that the string will accept the space char in the middle ?

Comment: one space character? In that case you could use `^[A-Za-z]*( [A-Za-z]*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

you are check help me validate date time type YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ or
YYYY-MM-DD

```
^(((19|20)[0-9][0-9])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|(((19|20)[0-9][0-9])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])T([01]?[0-9])|([2][0123]):([012345]?[0-9]):([012345]?[0-9])\.([0-9][0-9][0-9][Z]))$
```